# How to change the value of a Series element if preceded by N or more consecutive values to the value preceding it?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following Series `s`:

```py
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    0
```

For `N = 3`, we can see that the items at indices `3` and `6` are both preceded by `>= N` same value occurrences. Hence, their value should change the value of the items preceding them!

Output:

```py
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    1
```

So, far I have come up with this:

```py
(s != s.shift()).cumsum()
```

It somehow assigns a group id to consecutive occurrences of a value, but I am not sure in which way I should proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a [`rolling.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) with [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html):

```
N = 3
# check if an item is identical to the N-1 previous ones
# then shift (i.e. is one item preceded by N identical items?)
m = s.rolling(N).apply(lambda x: x.nunique()).shift().eq(1)
# mask those values and replace by the previous
out = s.mask(m).ffill(downcast='infer')
```

Intermediates:

```
   s  rolling_nunique  shift  eq(1)  masked  ffill
0  0              NaN    NaN  False     0.0      0
1  0              NaN    NaN  False     0.0      0
2  0              1.0    NaN  False     0.0      0
3  1              2.0    1.0   True     NaN      0
4  1              2.0    2.0  False     1.0      1
5  1              1.0    2.0  False     1.0      1
6  0              2.0    1.0   True     NaN      1
```

Same logic with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)'s [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

N = 3
# get "rolling" values as 2D view
v = swv(np.r_[np.full(N-1, np.nan), s], N)
# are all N values equal?
m = np.r_[False, (v == v[:, [0]]).all(1)[:-1]]

out = s.mask(m).ffill(downcast='infer')
```

Output:

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I think it works as expected. Could you please elaborate on it though?

Comment: I added some comments to the code, I recommend to run each intermediate to see how this works (e.g. `s.rolling(N).apply(lambda x: x.nunique())`, then `s.rolling(N).apply(lambda x: x.nunique()).shift()` then `s.rolling(N).apply(lambda x: x.nunique()).shift().eq(1)`). See update.